# How to upload pdf file in a flask-sql alchemy environment?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having troubles uploading .pdf and .doc files into sql alchemy as the files uploaded are detected as `NoneType`. I tried applying all the workarounds suggested but the error still pops up.

Below is my code as follows:

main.py

```
class UploadForm( db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key = True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(50))

    sector = db.Column(db.String(50))

    d_o_p = db.Column(db.Date)

    region = db.Column(db.String(20))



    file_data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)


@main.route('/doc_uploader' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'] )
    def upload():
    data = request.form
    print(data)

if request.method == "POST":
    title = request.form.get("title")
    sector = request.form.get('sector')
    d_o_p = datetime.strptime(request.form.get('date'), '%Y-%m-%d' ).date()
    region = request.form.get('region')
    file_data = request.files.get('file-upload')
    file_data = request.files.get('file-upload').read()
```

doc_uploader.html

```
<form  action="http://localhost:5000/doc_uploader" method="POST" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
     
            <input type="file"
            id="file-upload" name="file-upload"
            accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf"
            required
            />
</form>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Suggested solutions were to add in `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and set the field `file_data` as `LargeBinary` to accept files as blob type. Even after adding these in, the error still persists. A screenshot of the error is shown below:
[image: error_screenshot]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What usually works for me is to create a folder in my project folder then upload the pdf file to that location when the user uploads the pdf on button click. I then save the location with the pdf name into the database as a string.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But unfortunately I can't even get my pdf files(or any file for that matter) to upload or be sent over to the sqlalchemy database. It detects the file uploads as a NoneType object.